# how to keep vscode colors and not neovim extension color

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim, color-scheme

i'm using vscode, neovim extension and nvim v0.8, on WSL2. I really enjoy the workflow with the vscode theme (dark+ default), but when I enable nvim, its colors overwrite the vscode colors

[image: nvim not enabled]
I've tried using the default neovim colorscheme in my ~.config/nvim/init.lua and reading the Docs, but i couldn't find how to fix it.

[image: nvim enabled with colorSchema rosePine]

Comment: does the neovim extension has a theme definition inside, if yes, disable it in the package.json and build the extension again

Comment: Coul dyou please provide screenshots of the _same code_? It's not a proper comparison if you show completely different code :/

Answer (score 4):

For me, the issue was resolved my enabling “Neovim Clean” in the settings and then restarting VS Code.

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. To enable "Neovim Clean", you just need to add the following line in you user config: `"vscode-neovim.neovimClean": true`

Answer (score 2):

The setting in VS Code, 'Neovim Clean' will remove all plugin functionality. Which is great for a default setup, but for me I added a conditional in the file I set the colorscheme to "" and it worked.

```
if not vim.g.vscode then
... colorscheme set here for
else
return {{
  "LazyVim/LazyVim",
  opts = {
    colorscheme = ""
  }
}}
end
```

I'm using LazyVim so I'm setting it that way, but a similar setup should work just as well however you're setting it.

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work, I had to drop the ubuntu version and downloaded ubuntu20-04, then i installed nvim v0.8 again and got the color vscode without problems

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply using vanilla neovim, you can put the following code in `init.lua`:

```
if vim.g.vscode then
  vim.cmd.colorscheme = ""
else
  -- ordinary Neovim
  --
```

If you are using astroNvim (which I ran into the exact problem), I found a solution but it's not perfect because it requires you to modify the file `init.lua` a bit, but at least it works with neovim 0.9. Just add this code

```
if vim.g.vscode then
  astronvim.default_colorscheme = ""
else
  -- ordinary Neovim
  --
end
```

before the section

```
if astronvim.default_colorscheme then
...
...
end
```

The idea is that in VsCode, we will disable the `astronvim.default_colorscheme` and the following `if`-block will not be executed. In Neovim, everything is normal.